# $PATH variable location for backups

Tags: craft3

Folks:

This is surely something real basic. I have not been able to create a database backup manually or when updating.

- Mysqldump is installed.
- I know the location of mysqldump (/usr/local/bin/mysqldump).
- The log doesn't appear to reveal anything.

I have modified the .env file using the info from the [MAMP database backup article](https://craftcms.com/guides/database-backups-in-craft-3-with-mamp) (substituting the path for the MAMP one in the article). No joy.

According to the [config docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-config-generalconfig.html#backupcommand), I need to change the PATH variable.

The question is: how do I do this? Specifically:

- Where is this change made? Which file? general.php? .env? Elsewhere?
- What is the syntax to make this work?

Comment: If you followed the MAMP guide, you'll need to make sure you are [using MAMP’s PHP Executable your in Terminal](https://craftcms.com/guides/mamp-with-composer-and-mysql-on-the-command-line#using-mAMPs-php-executable-in-terminal)

Comment: I'm actually trying to do this on the staging server, not locally on MAMP. So I'm guessing things will have to be done a little differently.

Comment: When backups fail; you'll see an error in your craft/storage/web.log file which describes the error in detail. That would be useful info to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article was not quite right as it was for MAMP. What I did was add `putenv("PATH={$_SERVER["PATH"]}:/usr/local/bin"),` in the general.php file which resolved the issue. I didn't change the standard BACKUP_COMMAND in the .env file.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just editing the .env file; you also need to modify the config to make use of those options; which is part two of that article you linked to.

You could also try [adding a PATH variable to your .env](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/37349/configure-path-craft-uses-for-composer-and-php) which includes "/usr/local/bin" in it.

Update:
[The .env won't override an existing environment var by default.](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/tree/3.6#immutability) In most linux server setups this isn't a problem because the "www-data" or "apache" user doesn't have that set by default.

For MAMP, local dev or vagrant development; that path is likely set. If you want your .env settings to overwrite existing settings; change the web/index.php file to use `Dotenv\Dotenv::create(CRAFT_BASE_PATH)->overload();`
instead of
`Dotenv\Dotenv::create(CRAFT_BASE_PATH)->load();`